# jqPlot automatic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I have a serious problem with the canvas height of my jqplot graph.

It is an horizontal bar graph. The number of bars is dynamic, so the height of the canvas SHOULD BE dynamic as well.

What I get is that whatever is the number of bars, the height of the canvas is always the same.

`barWidth`, `barMargin`, `barPadding` are ignored.

---

Here is my code:

```
$.jqplot(tip, data, {
    stackSeries : false,
    captureRightClick : true,
    seriesDefaults : {
        renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions : {
            barDirection : 'horizontal',
            barWidth : 15,
            barPadding : 5,
            barMargin : 15,
            highlightMouseDown : true
        },
        shadowAngle : 135,
        pointLabels : {
            show : true,
            location : 'e',
            edgeTolerance : -40
        }
    },
    title : {
        show : true
    },
    series : [{
        label:'aaa'
    }],
    axesDefaults : {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
    },
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        }
    },
});
```

Does someone understand why height doesn't adapt automatically?